# What is the difference between a round number and a square number?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between a round number and a square number? I know that a round number can be circular in shape, and a square number has a shape similar to that of a cereal box (if the box is not rectangular). But I'm not sure if rectangular or triangular numbers even exist.

Comment: "I know that a round number can be circular in shape" What have you come across, which has given you that idea?

Comment: I think the evidence for that is zero.

Comment: How can an abstract concept like a *number* have a shape like a cereal box?

Answer (score 5):

This is, of course, a math terminology question, so the answer involves formal definitions from that field.

**Round number** generally means a number approximated or estimated such that it ends with a series of 0 digits; not an exact measurement. For example, 597 would be rounded to 600 for convenience and brevity in speaking. See Wikipedia: [Round number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_number).

**Square number** means the result of the squaring operation, usually starting from some integer; this corresponds to the area of a square with sides of some integer unit. For example, 1, 4, 9, and 16 are square numbers, because 1² = 1, 2² = 4, 3² = 9, and 4² = 16. See [Square number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_number).

**Triangular number** is the sum of the first several positive integers to some point; this corresponds to the number of things in a triangular arrangement. For example, 10 is a triangular number, because 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10. See [Triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

**Rectangular number** is the product of two sequential integers, also called "pronic" numbers. For example, 5 × 6 = 30 and 11 × 12 = 132 are rectangular numbers. (Alternatively, some use "rectangular" to refer to composite numbers.) See [Pronic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronic_number).

It may be of interest that the Nth rectangular number is always twice the Nth triangular number, and N more than the Nth square number (noted in prior link).

For a large list of other named types of numbers, see here: [Types of Math Numbers](https://www.mathgoodies.com/articles/numbers).